# "Unresolved variable or type" on module.id in PhpStorm

Tags: angular, typescript, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm building my first Angular 2 application with PhpStorm (2016.2.1) and I get the following error: `Unresolved variable or type`.

The error is just in PhpStorm, NPM compiles my code correctly. The error is just annoying because the file seems invalid.

[image: "unresolved variable or type" on module.id in PhpStorm]

I can fix this by declaring the module variable on top of my document like: `let module;`. But I don't feel like doing this in every Component.. What can I do?

Comment: See also: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207266109-moduleId-unresolved-variable-in-Angular2-components

Comment: Thank you Paleo! This ressolved my problem!